# Access Denied popup when logging in with MFP auth framework

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I have been seeing this error when trying to login to my app.

It is using the mfp auth framework

any explanation of what this is would be very helpfull

I see this in the simulator, I don't see this on the device, but wl.connect() always fails in the device

[image]

Comment: Without a reproduction, it is difficult to say.

Comment: So this isnt a standard error specifically from the auth framework?

Comment: I know this will display when you try to preview desktop or mobile web in a project in 7.1 (when it is in session independent mode), because those environments are not supported in session independent mode. How are you making this preview?

Comment: So this doent happen when i preview in a browser with mfp preview, it lets me login, when i try on a device, wl.connect fails, when i try in a simulator i get the message in the picture

Comment: Can you reproduce this outside of your app (i.e. with another app)?

Comment: Any news about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This was due to direct update, anytime a direct update happens i get this error, then i have to shut down the app and restart it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in simulator, deleting and reinstalling the app fixed this.